# How to rename multiple files from one extension to another in Linux / Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, file-rename

I have a number of files that end in a '.1', for example:

```
example.file.ex1.1
example.file.ex2.1
example.file.ex3.1
```

Is there a way that I can quickly rename them all without the '.1' at the end (e.g. example.file.ex1, example.file.ex2, etc.)?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suitable for [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Tried but apparently I don't have enough "reputation". =)

Comment: find -name "*.ex*.1" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed s/.1$//)"' _ {} \;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure bash solution:

```bsh
for curFile in example.file.*.1; do
    mv -- "$curFile" "${curFile:0:-2}"
done
```

Answer (score 13):

Yes, try this with [rename](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) :

```
rename -n 's/\.1$//' *
```

remove the `-n` (dry-run mode switch) if your tests are valid.

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: Could you explain why default ``rename`` doesn't work on Ubuntu or Debian? Seems like running ``/usr/bin/rename -n 's/.1//' *`` is working for me while default rename doesn't. I simply don't get it, both allow perl expressions but one works and another doesn't. What is the difference?

Comment: However sometimes program `rename` is something completely different on some Debians/Ubuntus I have come across...

Comment: So my explanations will helps to make the perl one the default.

Answer (score 3):

Another [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution using [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
for curFile in example.file.*.1; do
    mv "$curFile" "${curFile%.1}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! It works: 
f=file.zip; echo ${f%.zip} # -->
file